# Output redirection from grep not working as expected

Tags: grep, stdout

The pipeline

```
sudo ngrep -W byline -qilw 'get' tcp dst port 80 | grep -i ".*" |tee /tmp/output
```

or

```
sudo ngrep -W byline -qilw 'get' tcp dst port 80 | grep -i ".*" > /tmp/output
```

will not write anything to `/tmp/output` when I do an HTTP GET request.

Without redirection I can get some output on standard output. Why?

Comment: what is `ngrep -W byline -qilw 'get' tcp dst port 80`supposed to do ?

Comment: capturing HTTP get request, https://linux.die.net/man/8/ngrep

Comment: try removing -l (line buffering) option from ngrep

Comment: @rem : I want to try a test. Try opening a shell as root using `sudo -i` first and then execute the command. See if it works or not.

Comment: my understanding of `grep -i ".*" ` is : grep , ignoring case, any char `.` any number of time `*` . this grep make no sense to me. (unless filtering fancy display)

Comment: grep does not has any sense, it is just for testing purpose because `sudo ngrep -W byline -qliw 'get' tcp dst port 80 | tee /tmp/test`  works as expected. Tryin `sudo -i` does not solve problem

Comment: Perhaps it's just a matter of buffering then? have you tried adding `--line-buffered` to the `grep` (equivalent of `ngrep -l ... `)?

Comment: Thanks `--line-buffered` solved problem. More info about line buffering here http://askubuntu.com/questions/562344/what-does-grep-line-buffering-do

Answer (score 0):

The `grep` utility will do buffering of its output when it isn't connected to a terminal.  You will not see any output in the `/tmp/output` files until the output buffer of `grep` has been filled and flushed.

This will only be an issue for as long as `ngrep` is running.  Once `ngrep` terminates, `grep` will flush its output buffer before it too terminates.

This buffering is done for performance reasons.  Flushing a line of text to the output takes a short amount of time, but when massive amounts of data is involved, this slowes the pipeline down.

You may turn off the buffering that `grep` does, or rather, enable line-buffering.  With BSD and GNU `grep`, this is done with the non-standard option `--line-buffered`, so you'll get

```
sudo ngrep -W byline -qilw get tcp dst port 80 |
grep --line-buffered -i '.*' |
tee /tmp/output
```

Or, you could just remove that `grep` completely as it will pass all lines from `ngrep` on to `tee` (the regular expression `.*` matches on every line, no matter if it's empty or not).